# What happens to a thread, waiting on condition variable, that is getting joined?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I've got a class named `TThreadpool`, which holds member pool of type `std::vector<std::thread>>`, with the following destructor:

```
~TThreadpool() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pool.size(); i++) {
        assert(pool[i].joinable());
        pool[i].join();
    }
}
```

I'm confident that when destructor is called, all of the threads are waiting on a single condition variable (spurious wakeup controlled with always-false predicate), and joinable outputs true.

Reduced example of running thread would be:

```
void my_thread() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lg(mutex);
    while (true) {
        my_cond_variable.wait(lg, [] {
            return false;
        });
        # do some work and possibly break, but never comes farther then wait 
        # so this probably should not matter
    }
}
```

To check what threads are running, I'm launching `top -H`. At the start of the program, there are `pool.size()` threads + 1 thread where `TThreadpool` itself lives. And to my surprise, joining these alive threads does not remove them from list of threads that top is giving. Is this expected behaviour?

(Originally, my program was a bit different - I made a simple ui application using qt, that used threadpool running in ui thread and other threads controlled by threadpool, and on closing the ui window joining of threads had been called, but QtCreator said my application still worked after I closed the window, requiring me to shut it down with a crash. That made me check state of my threads, and it turned out it had nothing to do with qt. Although I'm adding this in case I missed some obvious detail with qt).

A bit later, I tried not asserting joinable, but printing it, and found out the loop inside Threadpool destructor never moved further than first join - the behaviour I did not expect and cannot explain

Comment: Welcome to SO! How are you signaling to the threads that they should exit? Is there a flag or condition that the main thread sets to indicate that they should return from `my_thread()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`join()` doesn't do anything to the child thread -- all it does is block until the child thread has exited.  It only has an effect on the calling thread (i.e. by blocking its progress).  The child thread can keep running for as long as it wants (although typically you'd prefer it to exit quickly, so that the thread calling `join()` doesn't get blocked for a long time -- but that's up to you to implement)

Answer (score 1):

> And to my surprise, joining these alive threads does not remove them from list of threads that top is giving. Is this expected behaviour?

That suggests the thread(s) are still running. Calling `join()` on a thread doesn't have any impact on that running thread; simply the calling thread
waits for the called-on thread to exit.

> found out the loop inside Threadpool destructor never moved further than first join

That means the first thread hasn't completed yet. So none of the other threads haven't been joined yet either (even if they have exited).

However, if the thread function is implemented correctly, the first thread (and all other threads in the pool) should eventually complete and
the `join()` calls should return (assuming the threads in the pool are supposed to exit - but this doesn't need to true in general. 
Depending on application, you could simply make the threads run forever too).

So it appears there's some sort of deadlock or wait for some resource that's holding up one or more threads. So you need to run through a debugger.
[Helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) would be very useful.

You could also try to reduce the number of threads (say 2) and to see if the problem becomes reproducible/obvious and then you could increase the threads.